# Open source java library for HTML to text conversion

Tags: java, html

Can you recommend an open source Java library (preferably ASL/BSD/LGPL license) that converts HTML to *plain* text - cleans all the tags, converts entities (&,  , etc.) and handles <br> and tables properly.

**More Info**

I have the HTML as a string, there's no need to fetch it from the web. Also, what I'm looking is for a method like this:

```
String convertHtmlToPlainText(String html)
```

Comment: Also [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631477/retrieve-text-from-html-file-in-java), which is distributed under the liberal [MIT license](http://jsoup.org/license).

Comment: By the way, jsoup supports HTML5

Comment: At least according the documentation it does not do what I've asked (convert the page to plain text, NOT HTML manipulation)

Comment: Here you are `Jsoup.parse(html).text()`

Comment: @cubanacan Thanks, good to know there is another alternative

Comment: +1 for Jsoup! And if you are looling for some "light" formatting of the output text (e.g. line breaks around ```<p>``` tags and similar), there is an example in the Jsoup repository, which is a great starting point: [HtmlToPlainText.java](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/).

The [TextExtractor](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html) class sounds like it will do what you want. Sorry can't post a 2nd link as I'm a new user but scroll down the homepage a bit and there's a link to it.

Comment: Here's the link to that class: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html

Comment: Thanks! I actually used the Renderer at the end

Comment: For the lazy: `String plainText = new Source(html).getRenderer().toString();`

Answer (score 3):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), it even shows the page after processing JavaScript / Ajax.

Comment: I see how it gives me the response as HTML, not text

Comment: Check .asText() [http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#asText()]

Comment: Thanks. I went for Jericho at the end, but I'll keep HtmlUnit in mind

Answer (score 2):

The [bliki](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/wiki/Home) engine can do this, in two steps. See [info.bliki.wiki / Home](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/info.bliki.wiki/wiki/Home)

1. How to convert HTML to Mediawiki text -- nediawiki text is already a rather plain text format, but you can convert it further
2. How to convert Mediawiki text to plain text -- your goal.

It will be some 7-8 lines of code, like this:

```
// html to wiki
import info.bliki.html.HTML2WikiConverter;
import info.bliki.html.wikipedia.ToWikipedia;
// wiki to plain text
import info.bliki.wiki.filter.PlainTextConverter;
import info.bliki.wiki.model.WikiModel;
...
String sbodyhtml = readFile( infilepath ); //get content as string
  HTML2WikiConverter conv = new HTML2WikiConverter();
  conv.setInputHTML( sbodyhtml );
String resultwiki = conv.toWiki(new ToWikipedia());
  WikiModel wikiModel = new WikiModel("${image}", "${title}");
String plainStr = wikiModel.render(new PlainTextConverter(false), resultwiki );
System.out.println( plainStr );
```

Jsoup can do this simpler:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sbodyhtml);
String plainStr = doc.body().text();
```

but in the result you lose all paragraph formatting -- there will be no any newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), it is available for several languages and does a really good job with HTML found "in the wild". It produces either a cleaned up version of the HTML or XML, that you can then process with some DOM/SAX parser.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the final result in plain text

Comment: Once it is in XML, you can implement a SAX parser to output only the text nodes (e.g. a DefaultHandler no-op implementations of all methods apart from `characters`)

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to go the other way.  But it looks like it can do what you need via [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Comment: I can't find any htmlToText() method - there are escaping of the HTML methods so that "<b>hello</b>" will be converted to "&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;" instead of to "hello"

Comment: Ahh, yes, I didn't see you wanted plain text.  This is true.