# how to convert HTML text to plain text?

Tags: java, html

friend's 
    I have to parse the description from url,where parsed  content have few html tags,so how can I convert it to plain text.

Comment: What are your precise requirements? Do you need to strip HTML tags? Extract the content of a specific tag?

Comment: i can able to extract the content,but the content have <p>zcc  dsdfsf ddfdfsf </P><span>sfdfdfdfdf</span>,
like the above i'm getting my data but i need to be a simple plain text.without those html tags

Comment: Similar question with good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518675/open-source-java-library-for-html-to-text-conversion/1519726#1519726. I used Jericho and it works fine.

Comment: You should mark this question as answered.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/240546/873282, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1699313/873282, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1518675/873282, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/832620/873282

Answer (score 42):

Yes, [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) will be the better option. Just do like below to convert the whole HTML text to plain text.

```
String plainText= Jsoup.parse(yout_html_text).text();
```

Comment: To keep the line breaks you can now also use `Jsoup.parse(html).wholeText()`

Comment: This is not working for me, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861739/how-to-parse-text-with-html-tags-into-plain-text

Answer (score 29):

Just getting rid of HTML tags is simple:

```
// replace all occurrences of one or more HTML tags with optional
// whitespace inbetween with a single space character 
String strippedText = htmlText.replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", " ");
```

But unfortunately the requirements are never that simple:

Usually, `<p>` and `<div>` elements need a separate handling, there may be cdata blocks with `>` characters (e.g. javascript) that mess up the regex etc.

Comment: For some background on why this will not work for the general case, and won't be f(u|oo)l-proof: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Love it... so simple, yet so powerful

Answer (score 10):

You can use this single line to remove the html tags and display it as plain text.

```
htmlString=htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

Answer (score 8):

Use Jsoup.

Add the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now in your java code:

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
        return Jsoup.parse(html).wholeText();
    }
```

Just call the method html2text with passing the html text and it will return plain text.

Answer (score 5):

Use a HTML parser like [htmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

For detailed answer : [How to remove HTML tag in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699313/how-to-remove-html-tag-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse like browser display, use:

```
import net.htmlparser.jericho.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RenderToText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String sourceUrlString="data/test.html";
        if (args.length==0)
          System.err.println("Using default argument of \""+sourceUrlString+'"');
        else
            sourceUrlString=args[0];
        if (sourceUrlString.indexOf(':')==-1) sourceUrlString="file:"+sourceUrlString;
        Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
        String renderedText=source.getRenderer().toString();
        System.out.println("\nSimple rendering of the HTML document:\n");
        System.out.println(renderedText);
  }
}
```

I hope this will help to parse table also in the browser format.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain why they downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend parsing the raw HTML through [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) which should give you output which you can write xpath expressions against.  This is the most robust way I've found of scraping HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a plain text representation of some HTML which included FreeMarker tags. The problem was handed to me with a JSoup solution, but JSoup was escaping the FreeMarker tags, thus breaking the functionality. I also tried htmlCleaner (sourceforge), but that left the HTML header and style content (tags removed). 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518675/open-source-java-library-for-html-to-text-conversion/1519726#1519726

My code:

```
return new net.htmlparser.jericho.Source(html).getRenderer().setMaxLineLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE).setNewLine(null).toString();
```

The `maxLineLength` ensures lines are not artificially wrapped at 80 characters. 
The `setNewLine(null)` uses the same new line character(s) as the source.

Answer (score 0):

I use `HTMLUtil.textFromHTML(value)`
from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>javautil</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jsoup, I got all the text in the same line.

So I used the following block of code to parse HTML and keep new lines:

```
private String parseHTMLContent(String toString) {
    String result = toString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "\n");
    String previousResult = "";
    while(!previousResult.equals(result)){
        previousResult = result;
        result = result.replaceAll("\n\n","\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Not the best solution but solved my problem :)