# How to parse text with html tags into plain text?

Tags: jsoup

```
 String tmpText = "\r\n HDFC Bank <\/a>\r\n <\/div>\r\n <\/td>\r\n";
 System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(tmpText).text());
 Jsoup.parse(tmpText).wholeText()
 Jsoup.parse(tmpText).wholeOwnText()
 Jsoup.parse(tmpText).ownText()
```

None of above are able to return just `HDFC Bank` text.
Is this bug or I'm doing something wrong

pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
           <version>1.15.3</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: `<\/foo>` are not HTML tags, only `</foo>` are.

Comment: ok, how to get rid of these special characters then ?

Comment: Just find&replace e.g. `<\/` by `</` beforehand? Or simply figure out why this corrupted HTML is there in first place and fix over there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because tags in the form of `<\/foo>` are **not** HTML tags.

HTML tags have the form of `<foo>` as start tag and `</foo>` as end tag.

Jsoup as being a HTML parser only parses HTML tags. So, Jsoup only parses `<foo>` and `</foo>`.

You have 2 options:

1. Find and replace e.g. `<\/` by `</` in your HTML string before feeding it to Jsoup.
2. Or, if this HTML string does not come from a hardcoded source, then simply figure out why this HTML string is corrupted like this and fix over there. I.e., step back and figure out how exactly this HTML string was entered, modified and/or saved in the place from where you obtained it. For example, if that process is unintentionally changing `</foo>` to `<\/foo>` because of e.g. a badly written HTML sanitizer, then that process obviously needs to be fixed accordingly. Or, if the end-user is already specifying literally `<\/foo>` instead of `</foo>` during the user input entry, then you need to block the user input entry with a validation error and let the end-user fix it.