# Convert HTML to text in Java

Tags: java

I have a Java string like this:

```
String str = "<table><tr><td>ALL,</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td> Please find attached file for this week<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>Thanks</td></tr><tr><td>Support Team</td></tr>";
```

I want output like this:

> All,
>
> Please find attached file for this week.
>
> Thanks,
> Support Team

Comment: That's not going to be easy as the html is not well-formed. Unless you use regexes, which is not recommendable

Comment: you should provide more context to the question. Do you need to format the string with carriage return (\n)? Giving you are dealing with a <table> I think you are looking for a templating engine such as FreeMarker or Thymeleaf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert HTML text to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607965/how-to-convert-html-text-to-plain-text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a proper html parser, but if you want something quick and dirty *and your html is well-formed* you can use something from package `javax.swing.text.html`:

```
    public static String stripTags(String content) throws Exception {
        String result = null;
        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
        Document doc = new HTMLDocument();
        kit.read(in, doc, 0);
        result = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

        return result;
    }
```