# Retrieve text from html file in java

Tags: java

I want to get text from html file in java

My `html` file is:

```
<body>

<p>vishal</p>
<strong>patel</strong>
<bold >vishal patel
```

I want to output like this

```
vishal 

patel

vishal patel
```

How to do this please help me

Comment: Do you want to read it from a a html file on the web, than you should use the following tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: Otherwise use indeed an XmlParser. By the way you didn't end the <bold> tag

Comment: Check [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: jsoup helps you extract it, but doesn't help you render it.
Found this though: http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp

Answer (score 23):

I have used a library called [**JSoup**](http://jsoup.org/).
It's very simple to retrieve the text-only part from a HTML file.
It's very simple:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

gives you the text from the HTML file

Comment: I want three different text so that i stored in String array But jsoup give me only one text ...

Comment: @user1206635 buddy, you gotta try some on your own.

Comment: @user1206635 JSoup gives you the text, you gotta do the rest. Nishant, +1 for ya !

Comment: @Vishal Android developer  JSoup have numerous selectors to work with tags. You can refer to the page http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax to check what fits you best.

Answer (score 4):

Better to use html Parser....I prefer to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) parser(opensource package)....

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
public class HTMLUtils {

    public static String extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
        return textOnly;
    }

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/RealHowTo/topics/java-language.html");
        System.out.println(HTMLUtils.extractText(reader));
    }
}
```